# Functional Analysis Question

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove a statement in Folland real analysis textbook but I am having troubles with it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

It says when X is a Hilbert space, weak convergence and weak * convergence precisely coincide. I proved weak convergence imply weak * convergence but having troubles with the other direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Hilbert spaces are self-dual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes this work on Hilbert spaces (as opposed to general Banach spaces, where it does not hold) is the Riesz Representation Theorem.

**Edit: more concretely:** suppose that $x_n\to x$ in the weak-$*$ topology. This means that 
$$
\langle x_n,y\rangle\to\langle x,y\rangle
$$
for all $y\in H$ (here we are looking at $x$ and the $x_n$ as functionals on $H$ via the duality $x\mapsto \langle \cdot,x\rangle$).

Now, given any functional $\varphi$ on $H$, the Riesz Representation Theorem guarantees that there exists $z\in H$ such that $\varphi(y)=\langle y,z\rangle$ for all $y\in H$. Then
$$
\varphi(x_n)=\langle x_n,z\rangle\to\langle x,z\rangle=\varphi(x).
$$
So $x_n\to x$ weakly.

Comment: Could you please kindly work it out for me? I am trying to see it through but it is not coming well.